# How to split each element of an array in zsh?

Tags: zsh

If I have an array:

```
x=( a:1 b:2 c:3 )
```

How can I split each element of the array on the colon?  I'm trying to do this in order to form an associative array.

I've tried several variations on this, but none seem to work:

```
print -l ${(s,:,)x}
```

Is this possible?  If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Are the provided answers helpful, or do you have further questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - further thinking got me to this solution, that might probably be applicable to the problem behind the question asked:
Loop through the array `x`!

```
> x=(a:1 b:2 c:3)
> typeset -A z
> for i in $x; do z+=(${(s,:,)i}); done
> echo $z
1 2 3
> echo ${z[a]}
1
```

I hope that's more helpful than the first answer(s) :-)

<strike>Since `x` is an array, you shouldn't forget the `[@]`, i.e. `print ${(s,:,)x[@]}`; thus your code becomes `print -l ${(s,:,)x[@]}`; but</strike> the solution is still another step:

```
> typeset -A z
> x="a:1 b:2 c:3"
> z=($(echo ${(s,:,)x}))
> echo $z[a]            
1
```

The assignement to the associative array is done with the output of the echo statement.

To clarify further and include your original example `x`:

```
> typeset -A z
> x=(a:1 b:2 c:3)
> z=($(echo ${(s,:,)x[@]}))
> echo ${z[a]}
1
> echo ${z[b]}
2
```

(edit: switched thoughts midwriting :-D, should make more sense now)
(edit 2: striked brainf*rt - similarities between zsh and bash aren't as broad as I assumed)

Comment: This feels close, but it's not totally there :(  The "echo" is forcing it to go through word splitting, which I realise I managed to oversimplify in my contrived example. :(    Nonetheless, this answers the question as posed. :)

Comment: BTW: I thought that `${x}` and `${x[@]}` were identical? (outside of double quotes)

Comment: my mistake - it is in zsh, in bash `${x}` is only the first element of an array. The echo is necessary exactly to apply word splitting on whitespace, as the assignement `z=(${(s,:,)x})` splits on :, so the first key is `a` with a value of `1 b` and a second key `2 c` with value `3`

Comment: @dominic-mitchel Is the added loop solution closer to real world application?

Answer (score 2):

`typeset -A x` will make x an associative array

```
$ typeset -A x
$ x=( a 1 b 2 c 3 )
$ echo $x[a]
1
$ echo $x[c]
3
$ x[d]=5
$ echo $x[d]
5
```

But i don't know how to split on the colon if you need to start from the string "a:1 b:2 c:3".